# Systematic way to troubleshoot systemd settings in unprivileged LXC

Tags: systemd

Every now and then I fail to get unprivileged LXC containers running. For some of them I find knowledge from others e.g., which sandboxing options should be disabled to make it work. This time with `freeradius`, I don't.

`freeradius` runs nicely in an unprivileged container, if I start it manually, without the sandboxing of `systemd`. However, I'd like to stay close to the Debian default setting.

Setting `systemctl log-level debug` I can see that it fails to perform some mounts, which is clear in an unprivileged container. But I have no idea, why `systemd` would do such mounts in the first place i.e., which option causes `systemd` to perform the failing steps.

Is there any systematic way to trace what systemd is doing and how the configuration should be adapted?